# Overriding superclass methods and access modifiers in MATLAB

Tags: oop, matlab, inheritance, overriding, access-modifiers

Consider the following simple class hierarchy:

#### A.m

```
classdef A < handle
    methods (Access = protected)    %# protected vs. private
        function foo(obj)
            disp('class A')
        end
    end
end
```

#### B.m

```
classdef B < A
    methods (Access = public)
        function foo(obj)
            disp('class B')
        end
    end
end
```

Class B inherits from class A and is supposed to override the protected `foo` method as public.

If we try to instantiate the derived class, we get the following error:

```
>> b=B();
Error using B
Method 'foo' in class 'B' uses different access permissions than its superclass 'A'.
```

The weird thing is if `foo` was defined as private method in the superclass `A`, the code works just fine when we invoke the overridden method:

```
>> clear classes
>> b=B(); b.foo()
class B
```

So is this a limitation/bug in MATLAB OOP implementation, or is there a good reason behind this behavior? (Code was tested on R2012b)

---

As a comparison, in Java the rules state that you cannot reduce visibility of a method in the sub-class, but you can increase it, where:

```
(weakest) private < package < protected < public (strongest)
```

Comment: Have you contacted TMW about this? Seems like a bug...

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis: not yet, I'm not sure if this is a bug or a design choice by MathWorks..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This appears to be a limitation of Matlab. I've tried all combinations of attributes. Matlab throws errors whenever the attributes are different, except when the method of A is private, in which case the attributes in B don't matter.

[image]

In other words, unless the method in A is private, the attributes of the method in A and B have to be the same. I guess this does make sense to some extent, in that TMW say "If a method is visible to the subclass, attributes have to be the same; if a method is not visible to the subclass, the subclasses can do whatever they like".

Comment: thanks @Jonas, I had tried all those cases as well.. From a design point of view, I see no reason not to allow overriding methods as such (lower triangle of your figure should be all happy faces!). After all, [Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) lets us increase access as I explained before, [C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6fawty39%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) offers the `override` and `new` keywords to allow overriding vs. hiding, while [C++](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2671448) have almost no restriction in that regard.. Something to consider MathWorks :)

Comment: @Amro Yeah, but people realized that C++ is a bit less restricive than it should be, therefore the books on how to do C++ "properly". Note that the smileys in the last row are really nothing to do with inheritance, as B does not see A's private methods. Moreover, if you make A's protected into public, you break A's design constraints, B is no longer an A.

Comment: @BarnabasSzabolcs: no argument there. As for the last point, I guess the workaround is easy; add a second public method `foo_public` to B that calls its protected `foo` without breaking the inherited interface