# Making virtual function private in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions, private-members

```
class A 
{
    public:
    virtual void fun() 
    { 
        cout << "A Fun"; 
    }
};

class B:public A
{
    private:
    void fun() 
    { 
        cout << "B Fun"; 
    }
};

class C:public B{};

int main()
{

   //Case1       

   A *ptr = new C();
   ptr->fun();
   /*
         OUTPUT : B Fun
   */

   //Case 2

   B *ptr2 = new C();
   ptr2->fun();
   /*
        ERROR:
        main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
        error: ‘virtual void B::fun()’ is private within this context
            ptr2->fun();
                  ^
        note: declared private here
             void fun()
              ^~~ 
   */
   return 0;
}
```

In case 1 : I am able to call the private fun() in class B , but why I am not able to call the private fun() in case 2?
Why fun() in class B is having two different kind of behaviour?
I mean to say that when I make pointer of type A then fun() of class B act as public function but when I make pointer of type B then fun() of class B act as private function.

Comment: Better question - change that `new C()` to a `new B()` on the first example - it will still work!

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484592/overriding-public-virtual-functions-with-private-functions-in-c

Comment: Access control applies to **declarations**. It doesn't matter if they refer to virtual functions.

Answer (score 1):

> In case 1 : I am able to call the private fun() in class B [...]

No, you are **not** being able to call / are **not** calling a `private` method in a class `B`. You are calling a `public` method from class `A` that happens to be overriden in the child class.

This is especially useful when unit testing a private method. You simply make your class inherit from a dummy base class that declares the method of interest as `public` and (possibly pure) `virtual`.

Comment: Then why is it not working in case 2?

Comment: Because you cannot call a `private` method outside of the class within non-`friend` scope. You need to understand the difference between *calling a private method* and *calling a public method which results in calling a private method*.

Comment: If I remove fun() from class B then calling ptr2->fun() will invoke A::fun() where ptr2 is of type B. So we can reach to A::fun() in this case. So whats the difference that restrict us to call the public method (of class A) which results in calling a private methodof class B)

Comment: Nothing restricts you to do so, but to call a public method of a base class with a derived class pointer, you'd have to upcast that pointer using `static_cast<>` first, like so: `static_cast<A*>(ptr2)->fun()`.

Answer (score 1):

Private-ness and public-ness is a purely compile time property of a member of a class/struct. The compiler checks if you have access to a member while compiling the code.

So in your code:

```
B b;
b.fun(); // Error! B::fun is private in this context!

A& a = static_cast<A&>(b); // `a` is a reference to `b`
a.fun(); // okay, A::fun is public.
         // It just so happen that A::fun is virtual,
         // So the function dispatched at runtime will be B::fun
         // But the compiler has no mean to check this.
```

The behavior at runtime is determined if the function has been overridden, and only if the function `A::fun` is virtual. By overridding a virtual function, **you must agree that expression using `A` will be dispatched to `B`, regardless what restrictions is on B**. Code calling `A::fun` polymorphically must work with any subclasses, because code that deal with the base class cannot know the derived classes.