# Calling private functions in C++ from base class pointers

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, private-members

Lets have a class **B** deriving from class **A**.
**B** has a private member `void secret()` while **A** has public `virtual void secret()`

```
B obj;
A* ptr = &obj;
ptr->secret(); //calls the private function secret in class B.
```

Now, the following code works successfully. Isn't this bad? Shouldn't the vtable also take care of whether the underlying function is accessible or not?

Here is [the source code](https://github.com/rachitiitr/DataStructures-Algorithms/blob/master/tricky-oops-problem.cpp) with more detail and good example.
Here is [my youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TVKsaq7Bohs) talking about the same.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484592/overriding-public-virtual-functions-with-private-functions-in-c

Comment: It is definitely a bad thing. It makes no sense for overridden function to have stricter access than inherence access.

Comment: The bad thing is the attempt to privatise the function. It would be *really* bad if `A`'s interface behaved differently depending on shenanigans in a different class.

Comment: This violates open/close principle in S.O.L.I.D https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID

Comment: Note that the access protection applies to *names*, not data or functions. It is a compile-time feature.

Comment: The issue is not the language, but the design of these classes.

Answer (score 2):

First of all **it is legal** – as the *vtable* does not take part in denoting the access during a call – as the C++ Standard [[class.access.virt]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.access.virt#2) says:

> Access is checked at the call point using the type of the expression
>   used to denote the object for which the member function is called (B*
>   in the example above). The access of the member function in the class
>   in which it was defined (D in the example above) is in general not
>   known.

That said, the [SOLID principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) are considered to be pillars of good code design. The 'L' in SOLID stands for the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), according to which:

> if S is a subtype of T, then objects of type T may be replaced with
>   objects of type S (i.e. an object of type T may be substituted with
>   any object of a subtype S) without altering any of the desirable
>   properties of the program.

So you see, by changing access of, let's say a public member in the base class, we would undoubtedly alter the interface of this derived object of type S, when trying to use it as a T. Thus constraining usage of it by other parts of the program, thus changing its properties and so breaking the *Liskov Principle*.

Furthermore, a comprehensive authority for such matters of usage and design would be the C++ FAQ, [According to which this hiding of derived members (virtual or not) usually indicates bad practice](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/proper-inheritance#hiding-inherited-public):

> Should I hide member functions that were public in my base class?
>   Never, never, never do this. Never. Never!

**For the avid reader:** The C++ FAQ says [the following about virtual methods:](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/strange-inheritance#two-strategies-for-virtuals)

> there really are two different basic ways to use virtual functions:
>
> Suppose you [...] you have a method whose overall structure is the
>   same for each derived class, but has little pieces that are different
>   in each derived class. So the algorithm is the same, but the
>   primitives are different. In this case you’d write the overall
>   algorithm in the base class as a **public** method (that’s sometimes
>   non-virtual), and you’d write the little pieces in the derived
>   classes. The little pieces would be declared in the base class
>   (they’re often protected, they’re often pure virtual, and they’re
>   certainly virtual), and they’d ultimately be defined in each derived
>   class. The most critical question in this situation is whether or not
>   the **public** method containing the overall algorithm should be virtual.
>   The answer is to make it virtual if you think that some derived class
>   might need to override it.
>
> Suppose you have the exact opposite situation [...],
>   where you have a method whose overall structure is different in each
>   derived class, yet it has little pieces that are the same in most (if
>   not all) derived classes. In this case you’d put the overall algorithm
>   in a **public virtual** that’s ultimately defined in the derived classes,
>   and the little pieces of common code can be written once (to avoid
>   code duplication) and stashed somewhere (anywhere!). A common place to
>   stash the little pieces is in the **protected** part of the base class,
>   but that’s not necessary and it might not even be best. Just find a
>   place to stash them and you’ll be fine. Note that if you do stash them
>   in the base class, you should normally make them **protected**, since
>   normally they do things that **public** users don’t need/want to do.
>   Assuming they’re **protected**, they probably shouldn’t be virtual: if the
>   derived class doesn’t like the behavior in one of them, it doesn’t
>   have to call that method.

So no changing of virtual member access in derived class is not mentioned here in either use-case of virtualization. As such, I'd also take it there is no known *good usage* for such tactic.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, a member function's visibility and it being virtual/non-virtual are widely orthogonal to each other. Other languages following a more strict OOP approach (such as Java) are not as flexible in this regard.

From a design perspective, hiding a public overridden usually doesn't make sense. However, consider that there is **private inheritance** in C++, which would make the base class A an implementation detail of B, and as such you wouldn't expose members of the base class.

Comment: I was about to write pretty much the same answer. Example of private inheritance with the `secret()` method: https://ideone.com/mOdMpO

Answer (score 1):

No this is not bad, as you are calling the method from the base class object pointer and in base class the method is declared as public. If you try B* ptr = &obj and try accessing method from ptr pointer then it will not be allowed.

So the type of pointer will decide the method specifier always.

Comment: I like this concise answer !  Access is controlled by the known type (of the pointer or the object, and not the object itself)

Answer (score 0):

As already explained very well by others, this works exactly as by the C++ rules.  The key design assumption of the C++ language is that the programmer knows what he's doing:

> C makes it easy to shoot yourself in the foot; C++ makes it harder,
>   but when you do it blows your whole leg off.
>   - Bjarne Stroustrup

Here, your design is flawed !  You want B to inherit from A (so B **is an** A), but at the same time, you want that it can't be used like an A (so B is not really an  A after all):

```
class A {
public: 
    virtual void greet() { cout <<"Hello, I'm "<<this<<endl;}
    virtual void tell() { cout<<"I talk !"<<endl; }
};
class B : public A {
private:
    void greet() override { cout <<"Hello, I can tell you privatly that I'm "<<this<<" incognito"<<endl;}
};
```

Humans can be confused by such paradoxical injunction.  The C++ compiler thinks you must have good reasons to do so and plays by the book:

```
A a; 
a.greet();        // ok 
B b; 
b.greet();        // error:  you said it was not accessible  
A& b_as_a = b; 
b_as_a.greet();   // ok:  you said that A's interface had to be used
```

If you want A's public functions to be inaccessible, you should tell the compiler by using non public inheritance:

```
class C : protected A {
private:
    void greet() override { cout <<"Hello, I can't tell you anything, but I'm "<<this<<endl;}
};
```

This means that a C is implemented based on an A, but that the outside world shouldn't knwow it.  This is much cleaner:

```
C c;  
c.greet();             // error, as for B 
A& c_as_a = c;         // ouch: no workaround: because the A inheritance is procteted
```

Typically, you'd use this kind of inheritance if you want to reuse A's features to build a C class with a completely different interface.  Yes, C++ can enforce tighter rules if you ask :-).

Typically, you would exposed completely different functions.  But what if you'd want to use one of A's public function for convenience, it's easy:

```
class C : protected A {
private:
    void greet() override { cout <<"Hello, I can't tell you anything, but I'm "<<this<<endl;}
public: 
    using A::tell;     // reuse and expose as it is
};
```